# Required positional argument python3 turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

may I know what did I do wrong with this code? I intended to make a square with turtle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXQwS.png

Comment: `turtle.Turtle()` with parenthesis

Comment: BTW, please include the actual code and error message in the question in the future and not just a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir. I will take note on that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not instantiate your turtle on line 2. You need to add parenthesis to the end of the line like this:

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle.forward(100)
```

The value `turtle.Turtle` returns the class Turtle. The class is a description of how all turtles operate. Whereas, using `tutle.Turtle()` asks the class to create an instance of itself, a new baby turtle that follows the rules of Turtle-life and can move about on it's own independent of all other turtles that live on this Earth.